# Если нет href у тега "a"

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

Вопрос наверное глупый, но все же. При парсинге с помощью `BeautifulSoup` хочу парсить ссылки в пагинации, а у тега `a` нет атрибута `href`. Как тогда парсить ссылку?

---

**UPDATE:**
Прошу прощения, реально сглупил. Сам сайт:
https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-audi/

Comment: не плохо было бы, если бы вы добавили весь пример такого тега

Comment: Если у тега `a` нет атрибута `href`, то это скорее всего не ссылка, а якорь. См. http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

Comment: Вы хотя бы ссылку на сайт который парсить хотите дайте. А то как-то с подробностями у Вас не задалось. Вангую что там скриптом просто строки в представление добавляются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения этой проблемы: так как линки отличаются только номером страницы, поэтому можно создать эти ссылки самостоятельно при помощи цикла. С помощью xpath `('//span[@class="page-item mhide"]//text()')[-1]` получаем номер последний страницы.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-audi/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
page = tree.xpath('//span[@class="page-item mhide"]//text()')[-1]
links_paginations = []
for i in range(1, int(page) + 1):
    links_paginations.append(f'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-audi/?page={i}')

print(links_paginations)
```